# Deploy docker image on osx to Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose

I want to deploy a simply docker container to my Kubernetes cluster. I'm on Docker for Mac (Edge mode since that's what supports Kubernetes), and I don't know how to push my image to my Google Cloud Container Registry.

Following the docs, I run:

`docker stack deploy --compose-file ./docker-compose.yml my-app`

and I get this in return:

> Ignoring unsupported options: build
>
> this node is not a swarm manager. Use "docker swarm init" or "docker
>   swarm join" to connect this node to swarm and try again

And here is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: ./
    environment:
      FLASK_APP: myApp
      FLASK_ENV: development
    command: flask run --host=0.0.0.0
    ports:
      - "9090:5000"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
volumes:
  data:
    driver: local
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does `docker stack ls` return?

Answer (score 1):

To push a Docker image to a remote Docker registry you need to follow the next steps:

1. Build your Docker image, e.g., `docker build .`
2. Tag your image with name of remote registry `docker tag <image_name> <repository_name_or_address>/<image_name>`
3. Login to the remote registry using `docker login <repository_name_or_address>` command
4. Push your image using `docker push <repository_name_or_address>/<image_name>` command

Steps for authorization can differ for various types of repositories. For Google Cloud Container Registry, you need to look through [this link](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/pushing-and-pulling). For more information, you can also visit the [link](https://docs.docker.com/docker-cloud/builds/push-images/) on the Docker official site.

After you push the image to the remote Docker registry, you can use it in Kubernetes. The simplest command for that is `kubectl run <name_of_your_deployment> --image=<repository_name_or_address>/<image_name>`

It is possible that you will need to configure Kubernetes for pulling images from your private repository. In this case, use instructions posted [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/).